# Permanently disable Wi-Fi network authentication popup

Tags: networking

is there any way I can disable following popup permanently? I am using Ubuntu as KIOSK, and this appears and stays there forever.

[image]

I want device to auto connect, because it syncs data from server. So it has to stay online. But whenever there is any problem in connection, this popup appears. Is there any way I can get system to keep retrying in background, but don't show this popup.

Comment: are you using wireless to connect to a network?

Answer (score 0):

If the Wi-Fi Network Authentication pop-up keeps appearing, there is likely something wrong with the connection configuration.

Try removing (forgetting) the connection, and establishing it again fresh.

To **remove** (forget) a **network** connection via **Terminal**:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETWORKNAME
```

To **remove** (forget) a **network** connection via **UI**:

Settings > Wi-Fi > Settings (gears icon) on the SSID name you want to change > Forget Network button.

Comment: I want device to auto connect, because it syncs data from server. So it has to stay online. But whenever there is any problem in connection, this popup appears. Is there any way I can system to keep retrying in background, but don't show this popup.

Comment: I thought the only reason this authentication popup would appear is for initial authentication or if the wireless AP password had changed. Does the connection re-establish if you just hit the Connect button, or do you have to type a new password? Also, from the image it looks like you're connecting to a 4G hotspot, is that right?

Comment: I found a workaround. What if I keep looking for PID by `ps aux | grep nm-applet` and just kill that process. What you think?